Neighbourhood between two disjoint open sets
Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, and consider open subsets $A,B \subset X$ such that $A\cap B = \emptyset$ but $cl(A) \cap cl(B) = \{x\}$ for some $x\in X$. Can I say that there exists some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that the ball centred at $x$ with radius $\varepsilon$ doesn't intersect $A$ nor $B$?

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Nobody will understand what "neighborhood between two sets" means.  There is no such terminology. So it makes no sense.

Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space, and let $S \subseteq X$.
$\text{cl}(S) = \{ x \in X : A \cap S \neq \emptyset, \forall A \text{ neighborhood of } x\}$.
In your case, let $U$ be a ball centered in $x$ and of radius $\epsilon > 0$, $U$ is an open neighborhood of $x$, and $x \in \text{cl}(A) \cap \text{cl}(B)$, so $U \cap A \neq \emptyset$ and $U \cap B \neq \emptyset$.
